# combining multiple ggplot geom into one figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can generate the following as two figures, but cannot figure out how to combine them into a single figure with the bars stacked above the density stacked above the "rug":

```
bars <- data.frame( start=c(1,34,67,98), stop=c(34,67,98,125), label=c(1,2,1,3) )
points <- data.frame( x=c(16,29,37,52,58,68,77,89,103,114) )
ggplot(bars, aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin=label-1, ymax=label, fill=label)) + geom_rect()
ggplot(data=points, aes(x=x)) + geom_density() + geom_rug()
```

I've tried things like:

```
    ggplot(bars, aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin=label-1, ymax=label, fill=label)) + 
 geom_rect() + 
    geom_density(data=points, aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_rug(data=points, aes(x=x))
```

but it appears that the later geom_X calls mess up the first call:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'label' not found

Comment: Could you add pics showing current and expected output?

Comment: The question of how to lay a density plot over a histogram using ggplot2 has been asked and answered multiple times. Have you done any searching. What has been the problem with other questions and an answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different variables mapped to *x* and *y* in each part of the plot. So you have to pull the `aes()` specification out of the original `ggplot()` call (which makes it apply to all geoms), and instead specify it differently for each geom. Then you have to specify which data each `geom` should use. Something like:

```
ggplot(bars) + 
    geom_density(data = points, aes(x = x, y = stat(scaled))) + 
    geom_rug(data = points, aes(x = x)) +
    # Will use the default bars data
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin=label-1, ymax=label, fill=label))
```

Comment: Despite all the reading I've done on ggplot, I never caught the bit about how spec'ing aes() in the ggplot() call forced it to apply to all geoms! Thank you for that clarification! As a lagniappe, is there a way to link axes scale commands to specific geoms. As written, the density and bars overlap. I found some "kluge" fixes, but nothing elegant (i.e., the right way). Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
    ggplot(bars, aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin=label-1, ymax=label, fill=label)) + 
      geom_rect()+
      geom_rug(data=points, aes(x=x),inherit.aes = F)+
      geom_density(data=points,aes(x=x,y=stat(scaled)),inherit.aes = F)
 #need a y argument in geom_density. 
#This is from @Marius' answer. Aim is to show inherit.aes usage
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
bars <- data.frame( start=c(1,34,67,98), stop=c(34,67,98,125), label=c(1,2,1,3) )
points <- data.frame( x=c(16,29,37,52,58,68,77,89,103,114) )
points2<- data.frame(x=density(points$x)$x,y= density(points$x)$y * max(bars$label)*100)
ggplot()+  geom_rect(data = bars, aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin=label-1, ymax=label, fill=label)) +
  geom_line(data = points2,aes(x=x,y=y))
```

[image: imagen]